# Javascript input issue

Tags: javascript, php

I have written a code for redirecting the page on submitting the form.
I have a drop down and textbox in that form.
I typed  `</script>` as input for the textbox , which had lead to normal excution but  with `);` on screen.

this is what i got from my firebug tool

```
<script type="text/javascript">
loadSearch('Customer','
</script>
');
```

PHP CODE for submit

```
<?php
if($_POST['searchButton']){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>loadSearch('".$_REQUEST['search_details']."','".$_REQUEST['search_input']."'); </script>";
}
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function loadSearch(selM,selK){
    document.location.href="index.php?pg=search&selM="+selM+"&selK="+selK;
}//loadSearch
```

Note: `$_REQUEST['search_input']` is the textbox and if the textbox is given with `</script>` as input

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. Please improve your question.

Comment: I tried to edit your question so it is at least clear what is text and what is code, but still the first paragraph is a mess, and I don't know which of those `)` and `;` are part of the question. Please edit this, put inline code fragments in backticks, and rephrase the question.

Comment: @Chilion shouldn't it be the **question?**

Comment: You have neither described a problem nor asked a question. How can we help you?

Comment: @Shikhar Bhardwaj Yep. Changed, tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are dumping the request values into your page without doing any escaping of them. Since this is JavaScript, one quick fix is to use `json_encode()` to encode the values as JSON:

```
<?php
if($_POST['searchButton']){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>loadSearch(".
           str_replace(json_encode($_REQUEST['search_details']), '<', '\x3C') . ", " .
           str_replace(json_encode($_REQUEST['search_input']), '<', '\x3C').
           ");</script>";
}
?>
```

Also, your  function should be using `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
function loadSearch(selM,selK){
    document.location.href="index.php?pg=search&selM="+
                           encodeURIComponent(selM) + "&selK=" + 
                           encodeURIComponent(selK);
}
```

But the question remains: if what you really want to do is redirect the user to a search page, why are you using this roundabout script approach in the first place? Why not just do a [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) directly from your PHP?

Comment: @NMN Did you delete the `'` (single quote) before and after the part for `search_input`? You'll need to do that.

Comment: redirection is happening;but the url becomes           /index.php?pg=search&selMod=Customer&selKey="<%2Fscript>"; i want it as /index.php?pg=search&selMod=Customer&selKey=</script>;

Comment: @NMN The `%2F` is expected. That is the correct way to represent the value `/` in a URL query value. Regarding the pair of quotes that you are seeing there, I ask again, did you make sure to remove the two `'`s before and after the `search_input` part?

Comment: yes;i used the json_decode when displaying in the textbox

Comment: @NMN Can you paste the current PHP code that you are trying into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something so that I can have a look?

Answer (score 2):

There is a severe vulnerability in you server side code. You should always clean strings which arise from user inputs using methods like `htmlspecialchars`.

Replace :

```
$_REQUEST['search_details']
```

and

```
$_REQUEST['search_input']
```

With :

```
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['search_details'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

and

```
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['search_input'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Not doing this can make your website vulnerable where a malicious user could include scripts to snoop on your users. What this function does is convert special characters like `<` to html HTML character entities like `&lt;` so that it can't be interpreted as code by the browser on the client side.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is not the right tool for this job. The values will be incorrectly interpreted in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

\Why do you not consider to use plain javascript without any php?

```
<input type="text" id="selM">
<input type="text" id="selK">
<input type="button" onclick="loadSearch(document.getElementById('selM').value,document.getElementById('selK').value);">
```